# Authorization header in aws requires signed parameter

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a aws request call and I get this following error while setting up the queue.
com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: Authorization header requir
es 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter/
What does this mean? How do i set the sign through java code ?

Comment: Are you using the AWS SDK or something similar?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the URL http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html

Comment: Based on the error it seems that you are accessing a AWS Service which requires temporary AWS credentials which needs to be passed in header using AWS signature4 signing process.

Comment: @Ashan not necessarily *temporary* credentials.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the correction. True not always needed for the signing process.

Comment: @sinasur, please *show* your code.

Comment: Here is my code @Michael-sqlbot      
 public static String initializeQueue(String queueName, AmazonSQS sqs) {
  String urlQueue="";
  Region usEast1 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
  
  sqs.setRegion(usEast1);
  GetQueueUrlResult queueUrl = sqs.getQueueUrl(queueName);
  urlQueue= parseQueueURL(queueUrl.toString());
  return  urlQueue;

Comment: I get an error on getqueueURL line

Comment: @whitfin yes am using AWS sdk.

Comment: Please edit the code into the actual question.  It's very difficult to read in a comment.  Where are you setting the AWS Access Key ID and Secret?